# Remove unknown column in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

Im making a treeview but I Have some problems with it:

Im getting the data and it is displayed in treeview but The First Value `listResult[1]` is missing (its shifting in a undefined column to the left)... What is the problem here? What is the column with no name? 
In addition, when I add a addition value before the `value=(listResult[1]...` for example `value=("",listResult[1]...`... the value-shifting problem is solved but the Unknown Column is still there...
[image]
'''

def findAllResult():

```
findAllResultInfo1=resultsFindAllFirstNameEntered.get()
findAllResultInfo2=resultsFindAllLastNameEntered.get()
findAllResultInfo3=resultsFindAllCategoryEntered.get()
if findAllResultInfo3=="Chemistry":
    resultsTree_1["columns"]=("#0","1","2","3","4","5")
    resultsTree_1.column("#0", width=50, minwidth=25)
    resultsTree_1.column("1", width=50, minwidth=25)
    resultsTree_1.column("2", width=50, minwidth=25)
    resultsTree_1.column("3", width=50, minwidth=25)
    resultsTree_1.column("4", width=50, minwidth=25)
    resultsTree_1.column("5", width=50, minwidth=25)
    resultsTree_1.heading("#0",text="ID",anchor=tk.W)
    resultsTree_1.heading("1",text="First Name",anchor=tk.W)
    resultsTree_1.heading("2",text="Last Name",anchor=tk.W)
    resultsTree_1.heading("3",text="3",anchor=tk.W)
    resultsTree_1.heading("4",text="4",anchor=tk.W)
    resultsTree_1.heading("5",text="5",anchor=tk.W)
    findAllResSQL="SELECT * FROM openlaboratory.lab_res_chem WHERE res_chem_f_name = %s AND res_chem_l_name = %s;"
    mydb=connectToServer(serverSettingsUser,serverSettingsPassword,serverSettingsPortNumber,serverSettingsHost)
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(findAllResSQL,(findAllResultInfo1,findAllResultInfo2, ))
    findAllResResult=mycursor.fetchall() 
    i=0
    for listResult in findAllResResult:
        resultsTree_1.insert("", i, text=listResult[0], values=( listResult[1],listResult[2],listResult[3],listResult[4],listResult[5]))
        =i+1
```

Comment: instead of `values=( listResult[1],  listResult[2], ..., listResult[20])` you can use slicing - `values=listResult[1:21]` - eventually with `tuple()` if it will be needed - `values=tuple(listResult[1:21])`

Comment: Hi. So the value `listResult[1]` is not missing per se... it is moved to the Unknown Column... If I change the `values=( listResult[1], listResult[2]...` to `values=( " ", listResult[1], listResult[2]...` All is fine, but the Unknown Column is still there... So the real problem is that the values are inserted from the NoName Column... The solution is to remove the NoName Column but I dont know how (because I dont know from where dose the column come from)

Comment: `#0` always exists, you're basically creating it twice, try `resultsTree_1["columns"]=("1","2","3","4","5")`

Comment: Problem solved... NoName Column  is removed... tnx for the info... :)

Answer (score 1):

Best I can tell it's creating a conflict between referring to a named column, or an index position, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746617/4777984.

As reproduced in:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

master = tk.Tk()

resultsTree_1=ttk.Treeview(master)
resultsTree_1["columns"]=("#0","1","2","3","4","5")

resultsTree_1.column("#0", width=50, minwidth=25)
resultsTree_1.column("1", width=50, minwidth=25)
resultsTree_1.column("2", width=50, minwidth=25)
resultsTree_1.column("3", width=50, minwidth=25)
resultsTree_1.column("4", width=50, minwidth=25)
resultsTree_1.column("5", width=50, minwidth=25)
resultsTree_1.heading("#0",text="ID",anchor=tk.W)
resultsTree_1.heading("1",text="First Name",anchor=tk.W)
resultsTree_1.heading("2",text="Last Name",anchor=tk.W)
resultsTree_1.heading("3",text="3",anchor=tk.W)
resultsTree_1.heading("4",text="4",anchor=tk.W)
resultsTree_1.heading("5",text="5",anchor=tk.W)

resultsTree_1.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

[image]

Removing the extra `"#0"` seems to correct this:

`resultsTree_1["columns"]=("1","2","3","4","5")`

[image]

Interestingly, adding a `#` in front of the numbers will also correct this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

master = tk.Tk()

resultsTree_1=ttk.Treeview(master)
resultsTree_1["columns"]=("#0","#1","#2","#3","#4","#5")
names = ("ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "3", "4", "5")

for c, t in zip(resultsTree_1["columns"], names):
    resultsTree_1.column(c, width=50, minwidth=25)
    resultsTree_1.heading(c, text=t, anchor=tk.W)

resultsTree_1.pack()
master.mainloop()
```