# Tkinter Treeview header sticky to right side of the table

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, treeview

need your help....

[treeview table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oetS7.png)

I need to get rid of that empty space after I move columns with mouse to the left side. What option can do that?
Thanks a lot!

Code#

```
def treeview_table_AI():
columns = tuple(tbl_for_balance_actual_after[['Currency', 'Account','Account ID', 'Reserves', 'After']].copy().columns)
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')
style.configure('Treeview',background='#F5F5F5', foreground='black', fieldbackground='whitesmoke')
style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', 'silver')])

tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_for_table2, height = 12)
tree.pack(side = LEFT, fill="both", expand=1)

tree['columns'] = columns
tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tree.column('Currency', width=96, anchor=W)
tree.column('Account', width=96, anchor=W)
tree.column('Account ID', width=97, anchor=CENTER)
tree.column('Reserves', width=97, anchor=W)
tree.column('After', width=97, anchor=W, stretch=False)

tree.heading('#0', text='', anchor=W)
tree.heading('Currency', text='Currency', anchor=W)
tree.heading('Account', text='Account', anchor=W)
tree.heading('Account ID', text='Account ID', anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading('Reserves', text='Amount before', anchor=W)
tree.heading('After', text='Amount after', anchor=W)

records = tbl_for_balance_actual_after[['Currency', 'Account','Account ID', 'Reserves', 'After']].copy().to_records(index=False)
final_records = list(records)
count=0
for row in final_records:
    list_of_row = list(row)
    tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=list_of_row)
    tree.tag_configure('gray', background='#cccccc')
    count =count + 1
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame_for_table2, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
tree.configure(yscroll=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
```

Comment: Please give [mre]. I dont know where you coming from and therefore I need to assume the issue.

Comment: You can also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535909/13629335) Im sure the right option will be there.

Comment: thanks for your response. I've added a code

Comment: problem is that when I select the last column to move to the left there's a extra empty space. I want the last column to be stuck to bord

Comment: Didnt solve `stretch=True` in the last column your problem? I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: yep, it solved :) I'm still learning so for me a lot of silly mistakes :) thanks a lot for your time! appreciate!

Comment: In the future, please remember to provide properly formatted code, including proper indentation, in your questions. See [ask] and [example] for more information.